# football / soccer software design pattern

Tags: database, design-patterns, software-design

A basic question.

Think of football/soccer.
I thought about making a design pattern for it, but wanted to know if there is already one out there.

It goes as follwing:

I want to create a football player.

We have a gender. (Male and Female).

A gender have a Series Category (for example for young under 19, for young under 18 etc.).

That Series Category is placed in a region (or state whatever).

And that Region has its series' name (for example series 1, series 2, division 1 etc.).

For example, I want to make female, Senior, she plays in Birmingham, and is in the first division.

I want to map this into the database, but I wanted to follow a software design pattern, but I do not know if there is a software design pattern for this purpose.

My attempt is like this:

```
Gender
{
   int GenderID 
   GenderType 
}

SeriesCategory
{
   int SeriesCategoryID
   string SeriesCategoryName
   int GenderID
}

Region
{
   int RegionID
   string RegionName
   int SeriesCategoryID
}

Series
{
   int SeriesID
   string SeriesName
   int RegionID
   int SeriesCategoryID
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should design your database using normalization principles (read more here - http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php )

Regarding software patterns - the are no exact patterns for your case. But use best practices and principles like SOLID. Mapping code entities to database ones and vise versa is responsibility of ORMs, which are existing in huge number of variations for different languages and requirements (SQL/NOSQL, code-first/database-first etc).

So for your exact case with footballers and teams I think DB normalization is all you required at the moment.

Comment: Yeah this is what I went with. I will be using asp.net with EntityFramework as the tools.
Also thank you very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need all the attributes of "Series" separately. If that is not a necessity I would have created just a "Footballer" and a "League" objects. And probably one footballer can play in one league, but there can be many footballers in a league. Therefore there would be a many-to-one relation between "Footballer" and "League.

```
Footballer
{
    int FootballerID
    int age 
    GenderType
    League 
}

League
{
    int LeagueID
    String leagueName
    String regionName
    String categoryName
    GenderType
}
```

So there is a many-to-one relation between FootballerID and LeagueID. First you can create a league without any footballers in it.Then, you can create a footballer with its age and gender, and then you can add this footballer to a league by checking their age and gender restrictions in the league category. A team object could also be nice though.

Comment: Hm... The problem here is that all of the series', regions and leagues are predefined.
I think I get what you mean, but I think it would be more flexible to seperate them, if there are going to be more addional restrictions for the region etc.
But I would still like to say thank you for the answer.